# Why phonegap ipa is in installing loop?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, ipa

trying to install my app on iphone, but it stuck in nstalling loop.For creating cert and prov profie, followed this steps:
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac?page=2

I have already read some topics here, but i have checked all the steps 5 times and added my device.Wherer can be problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset your certificates from Apple developer member center. I had similar problem with the .ipa packages and that solved the issue.

Comment: Let me try one more time, but i have checked all the step 5 times , so i dont know.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this kind issue is because that your device id is not included in profile, please follow the steps and check it one by one:
*(Login to member center => Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles)*

1. Device ID (UDID) is correct.
2. Edit iOS Provisioning Profiles, make sure the device is checked in Devices list.
3. Download and use the latest profile to generate IPA file again.
4. Uninstall App and install the new IPA file.

Comment: BobGao I am really curious why its not working, because udid and other thing looks ok, i am creating 3 certificate and all the time same result.

Comment: @EdwardRyzhewski Hi, could you attach some photos refer your issue, how is the app status in iTunes and what looks like when it hangs there in your phone. Thank you.

Comment: i cant attach photos because i am not iphone boy, asked client and my friend to do it.But i use testobject to test some features and in testobject app installs and works pretty good.here are some screens:
http://imgbox.com/ZSJMiHbx
http://imgbox.com/7U28ih9f

Comment: @EdwardRyzhewski you can try your question at [Nitobi forum for Phonegap Build](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi)